# Prove that $f(r) = 0$ for $\forall r \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow f(x) = 0$ for $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ given $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Prove that $f(r) = 0$ for $\forall r \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow f(x) = 0$ for $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ given $f$ is continuous.

I know that the Dirichlet function is discontinuous everywhere because $D(x) = c$ for rational $x$ and $D(x) = d$ for irrational $x$. So in this case it would be implied that $f(x) = 0$ for all irrational $x$ since $f$ is continuous. So to prove the statement, would it suffice to just prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all irrational $x$? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Every real number has a rational sequence which converges to that real number. Also, you can use the coutinuity of $f$.

Comment: Any irrational number $\alpha$ is a limit of a sequence $x_n$ of rational numbers (for example the sequence of $\alpha$ to $n$ decimal places will do). By continuity $\lim_{x\to \alpha} f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)$.

Comment: And $\forall$ means "for all" so you shouldn't write "for $\forall r \in \mathbb{Q}$". Instead just write "for all $r \in \mathbb{Q}$" in plain English.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/65220/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q.\ $
since $\mathbb Q $ is dense in $\mathbb R $ we have a series $(q_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset \mathbb Q \ $ s.t $\ \lim_{n\to \infty} q_n = x$.

since f is continuous we have: $\ f(\lim_{n\to \infty}q_n) = \lim_{n\to \infty} f(q_n) $. thus:

$$\ f(x) =  f(\lim_{n\to \infty}q_n) = \lim_{n\to \infty} f(q_n) = \lim_{n\to \infty} 0 = 0 $$

Comment: Note that "a real number is actually an "equivalence class" of Cauchy sequences".